# How to get isolated storage image as stream?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have very uncommon problem. firstly let me tell you that i want to build a WP8 apps about images. I have some images stored in the project solution and using those for the apps and it is working fine. 
i am using one

```
public Stream ImageStream
    {
        get
        {
            return this.imageStream;
        }

        set
        { 
            this.imageStream = value;
        }
```

`}`

Now for the project solution images this Image stream i am calling like this

```
StreamResourceInfo imageRes = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("WindowsPhone;component/Images/Image1.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    this.ImageStream = imageRes.Stream;
```

Now the problem begins if I try to use any image from media library. I can store the file into Isolated storage and from their I can access the file. What I am doing is

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile Iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {
     using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, Iso))
     { 
         IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Iso.OpenFile(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                    data = new byte[stream.Length];

                    // Read the entire file and then close it
                    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stream.Close();                     
                }
            }
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

            // Set bitmap source to memory stream
            bi.SetSource(ms);
```

However i can use the image file and can show but you can see it is a bit map image, and as it is in isolated storage I can not use

```
StreamResourceInfo imageRes ...
this.ImageStream = ...
```

Any help how can I use this.ImageSteam Properties? any other ideas will be welcome. I am actually beginner in WP8 programming

Or Let me ask you a simple Question how can I read a image which is in isolatedstorage to `StreamResourceInfo` ?

If I can do that my problem is solved. please help me.

Answer (score 3):

**Save Image to Isolated Storage: **

```
String tempJPEG = "logo.jpg";

            // Create virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(tempJPEG))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
                }

                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

                StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
                Uri uri = new Uri(tempJPEG, UriKind.Relative);
                sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

                // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);

                //wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
```

**Happy Coding...**

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have gone through this site, and I can show the image in  my game container but it is a only the raw image not the crop image I want to display. So cropping is done by ImageStream Prpoerty, that is why I need to call it. after I get the hold of the image,

Comment: what you have posted is from Windowsphonegeek.com, I told you in my previous comment that I have already gone through the site, and not much help. My question was how to get the isolated image file as stream?, no answer till now. I know how to save file in isolated storage and how to retrieve them. The question is still open, However for time being I have used a different approach to get my code work.

Answer (score 2):

why execute a stream copy ?

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images

try something like

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("logo.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        bi.SetSource(fileStream);
        this.img.Height = bi.PixelHeight;
        this.img.Width = bi.PixelWidth;
    }
}
this.img.Source = bi;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that ImageStream Prpoerty is actually doing much more in the setter, it is not only set; but it is cropping my image and return that through get; so I need to call that ImageStream. I have actually done what you said.